# How can I set a config variable in a one-off Heroku dyno?

Tags: bash, git, heroku, environment-variables, config

I am writing a simple script that will run in a one-off heroku dyno (launched using the `heroku run` command). The script's objective is to get the hash of the latest commit on the master branch of my repo and set one of the heroku config variables to that.

I'm trying to execute the following commands to clone the repo into the heroku dyno, change directories to be in the directory created by the clone and then set the config variable to be the desired value.

```
heroku run "git clone https://`heroku config:get GITHUB_TOKEN`@github.com/<org>/<repo>.git && cd <repo> && `heroku config:set CURRENT_HASH=`git rev-parse HEAD``"
```

When I execute any and all of the commands that follow `heroku run` in my local terminal, it works fine. However, when I execute the command written above in a one-off dyno using `heroku run`, `heroku config:set` is invoked first and it sets the config variable `CURRENT_HASH` to an empty string. Then the git clone executes successfully (the config variable `GITHUB_TOKEN` is correctly read) and then `git rev-parse HEAD` is executed. So the output is like this:

```
Setting CURRENT_HASH and restarting <heroku app name>... done, v246
Running git clone https://<GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com/<org>/<repo>.git; cd <repo>; git rev-parse HEAD on ⬢ <heroku app name>... up, run.1538 (Hobby)
Cloning into '<repo>'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 330, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (330/330), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (222/222), done.
remote: Total 4635 (delta 123), reused 269 (delta 98), pack-reused 4305
Receiving objects: 100% (4635/4635), 8.95 MiB | 9.27 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2425/2425), done.
bbb748d543a511eed4986cddb68b292ce1be67ad //hash of the last commit
```

What I don't understand is why `heroku config:set` is executed first even though it's the last command. Also, when I try to execute `heroku config:get` or `heroku config:set` using `heroku run` without the backticks, the script fails with the error `bash: heroku: command not found`. That is why I use nested backticks for `heroku config:set...` and `git rev-parse HEAD` in order for the command not to fail with an error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Put it in a normal `.sh` file and execute that with heroku run. Most don't know the rules behind the Heroku CLI inside out but writing a shell script is pretty straight forward and consistent.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I put my commands in a `.sh` file and executed it using heroku run. I tried the `heroku config:set` commands both with and without surrounding backticks and I got the error: `heroku: command not found`.

Comment: The `heroku` command does not exist on the remote. However the environment variables on the remote can be set and retrieved as normal `export FOO=bar` `echo $FOO`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!